# Toggle visibility without stacking for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, toggle

I'm trying to toggle the visibility of div's so that it doesn't stack but instead toggles one at a time. The toggle (although stacking) part is working and the code is at the bottom but here is what I have tried (but this doesn't work for me):

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
      var specifiedElement = document.getElementById(id);
    document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        var isClickInside = specifiedElement.contains(event.target);
        if (isClickInside) {
           if(specifiedElement.style.display == 'block')
              specifiedElement.style.display = 'none';
           else
              specifiedElement.style.display = 'block';
            }
        else {
          if(specifiedElement.style.display == 'block')
              specifiedElement.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
}
```

Below is my code that works for toggle, but it currently stacks as many as have been clicked, how would the simplest way be to detect if a click on other toggle id then display:none for the current open one or all expect the one clicked so that two or more can never be open at the same time?

html:

```
<a href="#" style="margin-right:15px;" onClick="toggle_visibility('a');"> a </a>

<a href="#" style="margin-right:15px;" onClick="toggle_visibility('b');"> b </a>

<a href="#" style="margin-right:15px;" onClick="toggle_visibility('c');"> c </a>

<div class="toggle" id="a" >
a
</div>

<div class="toggle" id="b" style="display:none;">
b
</div>

<div class="toggle" id="c" style="display:none;">
c
</div>
```

javascript:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }

</script>
```

CSS

```
.toggle {width:100%; background-color:#F00; position:relative;}
```

For some reason it doesn't seem to be functioning for me on fiddle but does on my live version.

https://jsfiddle.net/3mcf55xf/3/

Comment: I've tried this also which stacks toggle but not sure how to make it close all open when next is clicked rather than stack: `function toggle_visibility() {
   function toggle(id){
      var el = document.getElementById(id);
      el.style.display = el.style.display==='none' ? 'block' : 'none';
   }
   for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; ++i){
      toggle(arguments[i]);
   }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is what you are looking for.

```js
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    $(".toggle").not($("#" + id)).hide(); //hide all div elements except the current clicked a element
    $("#" + id).toggle(); //show/hide the div element
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" onClick="toggle_visibility('a');">a</a>
<a href="#" onClick="toggle_visibility('b');">b</a>
<br/><br/>
<div class="toggle" id="a" style="display:none;">div 1</div>
<div class="toggle" id="b" style="display:none;">div 2</div>
```

Comment: Yes like that but where it doesn't only work if the text is same as the ID?

Comment: For example if click an image toggle, as in if it wasn't text that matches the id?

Comment: All HTML elements can have ID attribute like for example: `<img id="logo" src="nsc/logo2.png" alt="BrandLog" />`. Similarly all HTML elements can have class attribute like `<img id="logo" class= 'image' src="nsc/logo2.png" alt="BrandLog" />`.  You can use both ID and class attributes to get handle to HTML element and manipulate the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for info! So how would something like this work?
 `toggle_visibility($(this).attributes["name"].value);` should this work? could you show me an example, where it uses the name or something rather than this.text?

Comment: Updated code above to toggle `div`s based on `a` tag's name attribute. Note that id for each element should be unique.

Comment: Thanks for info and that's interesting solution that could be handy in future for other things. I've tested and doesn't work for my problem as it doesn't toggle on and off when clicked twice on the same "a name". Is it not possible to do with this or along these lines as this is working perfectly just I don't want more than one open at a time? `function toggle_visibility(id) {

       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';  
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';  
    }`

Comment: Before `var e = document.getElementById(id); ` put `$(".toggle").hide();`. That should hide all div's.

Comment: Great that hides the stack and only shows 1 ! Exactly what I want but it doesn't allow the div being shown to be closed on a second click (toggle) do you know what might be causing this? My html is like this: `<a href="#" onClick="toggle_visibility('a');">` `<div class="toggle" id="a" style="display:none;">`

Comment: Hope the above updated code is what you are looking for.

Comment: Exactly thank you very much can you explain in your answer how it works just so I can understand it for the next time? Thank you so much!